# Flutter web renders elements on the screen too large

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

Flutter web seems to render the elements on the screen way too large. Everything, from text, to `Containers`, to form fields, is massive. It is like everything has been zoomed in. It doesn't look good. I thought setting the visual density of the theme to `VisualDensity.compact` or `VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity` would fix it, but it doesn't seem to. Running the app on a very large iPad Pro does not enlarge the elements. Why might this enlargement happen? I work on another Flutter app that is not enlarged on web and am unsure of what the key difference is that is causing the different rendering behaviour.

Comment: Instead of editing your question to add the answer, you should answer it in the "answer" section

Answer (score 1):

This ended up being due to setting my mac display to "Scaled" with "larger text" in system preferences. It seemed to affect the web version and not the mobile simulators; I guess because the simulators are not under the mac display settings; they are their own device.

The fix was to set it to "Default for display":

[image]